# Existence of Hessian of convex conjugate

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Define convex conjugate of $f, f^*(x):=\sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}^n}\langle x,y\rangle-f(y)$. Then I want to prove this statement:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. Assume $f$ is twice differentiable at $x_0$ and $\det(D^2f)(x_0)=0$. Show that $D^2f^*(Df(x_0))$ doesn't exist.

---

I have tried to prove it by contradiction:

Since $\det(D^2f)(x_0)=0$, $\exists v\not= 0$, such that $v^TD^2f(x_0)=0$

$f$ is twice differentiable at $x_0$ and $f^*$ is twice differentiable at $Df(x_0)$ implies given $\epsilon >0$, $\exists \delta>0$, such that for all $0<\|x-x_0\| <\delta,0<\|z-Df(x_0)\| <\delta$

$\frac{\|f(x)-f(x_0)-(x-x_0)^TDf(x_0)-\frac{1}{2}(x-x_0)^TD^2f(x_0)(x-x_0)\|}{\|x-x_0\|}<\epsilon\tag{1}$

and,

$\frac{\|f^*(z)-f^*(Df(x_0))-(z-Df(x_0))^TDf^*(Df(x_0))-\frac{1}{2}(z-Df(x_0))^TD^2f^*(Df(x_0))(z-Df(x_0))\|}{\|z-Df(x_0)\|}<\epsilon\tag{2}$

Assume $\|v\|<\delta$, from $(1)$, we get 
$\frac{\|f(x_0+v)-f(x_0)-v^TDf(x_0)\|}{\|v\|}<\epsilon$

Then I don't know what to do.

I have only find references about the cases where $Df^2(x_0)$ is nonsingular. Could you give me some hints so that I can proceed further or provide me with some references? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We begin with these basic properties of conjugates, which do not require differentiability of $f$ or $f^*$. You can pull these from any basic convex analysis text:
$$f^*(z) = \sup_y \langle z, y \rangle - f(y)$$
$$\partial f^*(z) = \mathop{\textrm{argmax}}_y \langle z, y \rangle - f(y) = \{y~|~z\in\partial f(y)\}.$$
This second condition implies the following:
$$z \in \partial f(y) \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad y \in \partial f^*(z).$$
The notation $\partial f$ refers to the *subdifferential* of $f$; this is an
important concept in convex analysis, so do check out a good convex analysis
text (like Rockefellar) to review all of this.

Now to our specific problem. For $y=x_0$, $\partial f(x_0)=\{z_0\}$, where $z_0\triangleq Df(x_0)$. 
Therefore, $x_0\in\partial f^*(z_0)$. Now, if we could confirm that $x_0$ is
the *only* subgradient—that is, that $\partial f^*(z_0)=\{x_0\}$—then 
we could say that $f^*$ is differentiable at $z_0$, and $Df^*(z_0)=x_0$. But
we cannot! After all, we know that $D^2 f(x_0)$ is not positive definite, so
we cannot be sure that the supremum $\sup_y \langle z_0, y \rangle - f(y)$ has 
a unique solution.

So it is  possible that $f^*$ is not differentiable at $z_0$. But if that's the
case, then it's not *twice* differentiable, either, *which is exactly what
we seek to prove*. So let us *assume* that $f^*$ is twice differentiable at 
$z_0$; we will show that  still leads to a contradiction.

If $f^*$ is differentiable at $z_0$, then it must be true that $Df^*(z_0)=x_0$.
Substituting back in for $z_0$ gives us this expression:
$$Df^*(Df(x_0))=x_0.$$ 
Differentiating with respect to $x_0$ yields
$$D^2f(x_0) \cdot D^2f^*(Df(x_0)) = I$$
But this is impossible: since $D^2f(x_0)$ is singular, the product 
must be as well; and it cannot possibly be equal to $I$. 
Thus our assumption that $f^*$ is twice differentiable at $z_0$ is contradicted.

Therefore, even though we can't say for sure that $f^*$ is differentiable 
*once*, we can say for sure that it is not differentiable *twice*.

Comment: Would the downvoter please care to share what he/she sees as the problem here so it can be corrected?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I know when you differentiate the identity, why RHS is identity? Since it seems we only know the value of the function at a point. The derivative can be anything, am I right?

Comment: I can understand the confusion, because it seems like $x_0$ is a constant. But $Df^*(Df(x))=x$ is true *anywhere both derivatives exist*. So we can indeed think of both sides as functions of $x$. And the derivative of the function $g(x)=x$ is indeed the identity.

Comment: Think of this as a vector version of implicit differentiation, in other words.